# Autnenticate from different table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table called `customusers`. I want to authenticate from this table. I am successful in registering the users and storing in `customusers` table but i am not able to login using `Auth::atempt`. 
Below is my code

**auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'custom' =>[
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customusers'
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'custom_api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'customusers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'customusers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\CustomUser::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'customusers' => [
            'provider' => 'customusers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ]
    ],

];
```

**CustomUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class CustomUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guard = 'custom';

    protected $table = 'customusers';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'passcode',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'passcode', 'remember_token',
    ];



    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->passcode;
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::POST('/mlogin','Auth\LoginController@mLogin')->name('mylogin');



    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->middleware('guest:custom')->except('logout');


    }

    public function mLogin(Request $request){
        echo $request->input('username').' '.$request->input('passcode');;

         if (Auth::guard('custom')->attempt([
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'passcode' => $request->input('passcode')
    ])) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
    }
    }
}
```

I am unable to login. what am i doing wrong here please guide.

Comment: Are you using middleware in controller like this `$this->middleware('auth:custom');`

Comment: @JagjeetSingh no i am not using this. i was following some tutorial from web.

Comment: I have updated the code, added LoginController now.

Comment: If you are using custom guard then need to add in middleware in controller

Comment: I have added it like this  $this->middleware('guest:custom')->except('logout');

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly you can try using the https://packalyst.com/packages/package/sboo/multiauth for multiple auth tables.

Answer (score 0):

you should use custom guard when using Auth Methods.

so when attempting to authenticate users use this

```
Auth::guard('custom')->attempt()
```

Comment: i did tried it that way too. i updated the question too.

Comment: customuser case doesnt match your customUser class in auth.php

Comment: how can i match it, i am new to laravel